# Powershell Array Manipulation

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I have a CSV export file from a time sheet system in the following format:

```
Paynum,Employee,Date,Time
123,Joe Blogs,2016-07-10,08:37:29
321,Ivor Notion,2016-07-10,08:39:31
345,Herr Flick,2016-07-10,08:44:05
321,Ivor Notion,2016-07-10,12:23:07
345,Herr Flick,2016-07-10,12:24:15
123,Joe Blogs,2016-07-10,13:03:49
```

The output I'm trying to achieve is:

```
Paynum,Employee,Date,Time#1,Time#2
123,Joe Blogs,2016-07-10,08:37:29,13:03:49
321,Ivor Notion,2016-07-10,08:39:31,12:23:07
345,Herr Flick,2016-07-10,08:44:05,12:24:15
```

I've loaded the sample with:

```
$TimesheetData = @(Import-Csv $MergerFile)
```

but now I'm completely lost with the `for` loops.

Comment: Can you post the for loop?

Comment: I had a foreach loop but completely lost the plot from there.                  foreach ($row in $TimesheetData) {
 $row.Paynum
 $row.Employee
 $row.Date
 $row.Time
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Group-Object` to group the CSV data by employee, then build new objects from the groups:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' | Group-Object Employee | ForEach-Object {
  $props = [ordered]@{
    Paynum   = $_.Group[0].Paynum
    Employee = $_.Group[0].Employee
    Date     = $_.Group[0].Date
  }

  $i = 1
  $_.Group | Select-Object -Expand Time | ForEach-Object {
    $props["Time#$i"] = $_
    $i++
  }

  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $props
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

If the number of records can differ from employee to employee you need to ensure that all generated records have the same number of time fields (or at least that the first record has the maximum number of fields, even if some or all of them are empty), because PowerShell determines the columns to display in tabular output by the first object.

You can determine the maximum number of time fields from the grouped records:

```
$csv      = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' | Group-Object Employee
$timeCols = $csv | Select-Object -Expand Count |
            Sort-Object |
            Select-Object -Last 1
```

and use a `for` loop for adding the time columns:

```
$times = $_.Group | Select-Object -Expand Time
for ($i=1; $i -le $timeCols; $i++) {
  $props["Time#$i"] = $times[$i]
}
```

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers - Your script works perfectly. I've found I don't need to count any additional times as the script adds the extra column with a "Time#" number . I've found by adding extra group items (e.g. Manager   = $_.Group[0].Manager ) I can handle any extra source columns. The only question I have is how do I group for multiple days, so that each day is on it's own row?

Comment: `Group-Object Employee, Date`

Answer (score 0):

1. Group by `Paynum`
2. Sort each group by time
3. Take the first item in a group
4. Remove `Time`
5. Add `Time#1` = first item's time and `Time#2` = second item's time

```
$merged = Import-Csv r:\1.csv |
    Group Paynum |
    ForEach {
        $sorted = $_.Group | Sort Time
        $sorted[0] |
            Select * -ExcludeProperty Time |
            Select *,
                   @{N='Time#1'; E={$sorted[0].Time}},
                   @{N='Time#2'; E={$sorted[1].Time}}
    }
$merged | Export-Csv r:\2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: your script works perfectly but the alternative is slightly more flexible as the goalposts have now been moved - even so thanks for the help.